# What can an EFT tell one about the ''underlying'' theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, effective-field-theory

I was reading about effective field theories and wondering how much an EFT can tell you about the ''underlying'' theory which is then reflected in the EFT.  Can one extrapolate back from what one sees in the EFT to derive features of the theory for the high energy degrees of freedom?

As an example, general relativity is considered to be an effective field theory for quantum gravity, but that does not tell us much about what the correct quantum gravity theory would look like, with many people arguing that this underlying theory would be a string theory and not even a field theory.

However, are there cases where one can say more or come to definite conclusions about the underlying theory?  What is the systematic way for doing this?  For example, in [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.05664.pdf) of Pich on EFTs with Nambu-Goldstone modes, he mentions that one can ''uncover fingerprints of new physics scales'' from couplings in the EFT.